# Story references in conversation with The Living Stone (Vagrus: The Riven Realms)

Tags: reference, vagrus-the-riven-realms

A while back, I played a game called *[Vagrus: The Riven Realms](https://store.steampowered.com/app/909660/Vagrus__The_Riven_Realms/)*. At one time, during the main character's exploration of the titular Riven Realms, they encounter a friendly entity called The Living Stone. They end up exchanging stories (I've split and numbered them up):

> 1. You hear a story about a daring swordsman entering a maze of tunnels beneath a mountain with a fiery red peak.

> 2. This is followed by the narrated travelogue of a mercenary looking for pieces of a Dwarven artifact in a deadly forest.

> 3. Then you listen to a terrifying tale about a Necromancer who keeps returning from the underworld after being slain because of a covenant with Demons, becoming a more twisted Undead version of himself each time he comes back.

> 4. Then there is an intriguing fable about a rich madman who built a dungeon full of traps and monsters to challenge equally mad contestants in a battle of wits and recklessness.

> 5. You hear about all kinds of ludicrous beings: lizard kings, snow witches, and a bloodbeast, whatever that is.

I'm thinking that the first one might be a reference to *The Lord of the Rings*, though I'm interested if there are any other SF/F works which fit the short description.

The second one reminds me of something *Skyrim* / *Elder Scrolls* related (Dwemer artifacts and the like), but I doubt that's it.

The third one looks a bit like the story of Rhulad Sengar (Steven Erikson's *Malazan Chronicles*), but he wasn't a necromancer (though there was a deal involved).

As for the fourth one, I'm seeing a reference to an interactive fiction piece called *[Lock & Key](http://adamcadre.ac/if.html)*, by Adam Cadre, but I doubt that's it (though it really fits, from what I can remember of it, having played it some 20 years ago).

The last one seems to be a reference to various tabletops (*Dungeons and Dragons*, *Fighting Fantasy*, etc).

Are there any (un)officially confirmed references? I've googled around, and have come up empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these are all references to the [Fighting Fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighting_Fantasy) series of gamebooks.

The first story would refer to the first Fighting Fantasy book, "The Warlock of Firetop Mountain".

> The player takes the role of an adventurer travelling to find the treasure of a powerful Warlock, hidden deep within Firetop Mountain. People from a nearby village advise that the treasure is stored in a chest with two locks, and that the keys are guarded by various creatures within the dungeons. The player must then navigate the dungeons beneath Firetop Mountain, battle monsters and attempt to locate the keys.

The second is the third book, "The Forest of Doom".

> The Forest of Doom is a fantasy adventure scenario in which the hero character travels through a hazardous forest in search of the missing pieces of a magic warhammer needed to assist the dwarves in their war against the trolls.

The third possibly refers to Zagor (the Warlock from Warlock of Firetop Mountain). He is resurrected twice in the series, as you need to fight him again in "Return to Firetop Mountain" and "Legend of Zagor".

The fourth is the sixth book, "Deathtrap Dungeon".

> The player takes the role of an adventurer who decides to enter Baron Sukumvit's "Trial of Champions" and brave "Deathtrap Dungeon". Competing against five other adventurers, the player must defeat monsters, navigate the maze of dungeons and collect certain gems, which are the key to escaping and winning the Trial.

"Lizard Kings" refers to the seventh book "Island of the Lizard King", and the Snow-Witch is from the ninth book, "Caverns of the Snow Witch". Bloodbeasts also show up in the series.

Comment: Very nice, they seem to fit. I've googled more stuff from Fighting Fantasy, and I've come across Ian Livingstone, so it would seem that you're correct. Thank you! As an aside, any idea what the necromancer bit is? Could it be this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Thieves_(gamebook) ?